# Script creating multiple processes

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script which receives an input directory of movie files and and output directory for text files.
The script runs an external application which parses the movie files into text files.
The script also has the ability to run multiple process of that "Movie-Parser" at once (in parallel).

I get this weird issue:
When I run the script on a certain directory (with one or more files in it) it works perfectly. If I run the script and tell it to load 2 movies (for example) at once each time, it also works fine, and I see 2 processes running in the Task manager.
When I run the same run on a different directory, I get the same result.

But, and that's the odd thing: When I open to consoles, and run the script on one directory (with one file in it) in the first console, and run the script on the second directory (with one file in it) in the second console, suddenly, when looking at the task manager,I see 4 running processes instead of 2.

If I increase the parallel processes, I get even more processes in the task manager.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Show us the batch file...we need more info.

Comment: 1 -> 2 then 2 -> 4, sounds reasonable...

Comment: no, you see, when I run one batch with one file, I see one process. Then, I run another batch with one wile, while the first one is still running, and all of the sudden, I see 4 processes. So it's 1->1 and 2->4.

Comment: Is the process name called Batchrun, from this website: http://www.geardownload.com/system/batchrun-download.html If so, then 2 questions: 1) does it behave exactly same way on XP vs. Win7?; and 2) is it possible the program doing the conversion has a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the variables in your batch files.  Presumably both instances of your running batch file are using the same variables to store the path to the files.  The different instances my be cross-communicating if, for example, you are using your system environment's  %1%, which is shared across processes.

Consider adding

```
setlocal
```

to your batchfile.  See, for example, [this Microsoft documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx).